# Get variable name of Qt Widget (for use in Stylesheet)?

Tags: qt, variables, pyqt, pyqt4

In my application, a User clicks on any widget of my program (which are at the time; dormant) and picks a color for it.
This color will then be added to a stylesheet for that particular widget.

However, when the program ends and is started again, I would like that particular widget to retain its stylesheet.
I would like to not have to hard code in stylesheets for every widget. In fact, I'd rather not even know which particular widget is having the stylesheet.

What I'd really like to do is have a single style sheet for the application, and code the new color just to the particular widget clicked.

(ie: If the User clicked on a QPushButton and chose a stylesheet of { color: red},
I would like just THAT QPushButton red and none others.
So, if that QPushButton had a variable name of 'Clicky',
to the QApplications stylesheet I would add:
'QPushButton#Clicky { color: red }' )

To do this and not have to hard-code it in for every widget,
I must somehow convert the variable name of my PyQt4 widgets to strings.
How can I do this?

Thanks!

(I've read it can be extremely difficult to get python variable names from their values;
Is there any other form of ID for a widget that can be added to a stylesheet?)

---

PyQt4
python 2.7.2
Windows 7

Comment: I momentarily excited at QObject.objectName(), but so far have only managed to get it to work for retrieving class names (not instances) of subclassed widgets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to first setObjectName("somename") before an object is named, then objectName() will work, or even better - findChild(), or findChildren()

Example

header:

```
QButton foo;
```

class:

```
foo = new QButton();
foo.setObjectName("MySuperButton");
```

Then, finally in your QSS..

```
#MySuperButton { 
     background: black;
}
```

This also works similarly to CSS with

```
QButton#MySuperButton {
     background: red;
}
```

The logic behind why you'd want to set multiple object names similarly (for different objects), or use the granularity of only one type of widget with a specific name is also pretty much the same as CSS.

Comment: Hmm. Is my suspicion correct that Qt Designer does this automatically?

Comment: Set the objectname? .. I don't know. Should be pretty easy to figure out though. Make a UI, then try and qDebug() << myObject.objectName();

Comment: Yes, Qt Designer files (combined with uic) set the object name automatically.

Comment: This is a very usefull answer, but was not easy to find, as the question is missleading.