# Qt - Temporarily disable all events or window functionality?

Tags: python, qt, events, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a Qt program with many buttons, user-interactable widgets, etc.
At one stage in the program, I would like all the widgets to temporarily 'stop working'; stop behaving to mouse clicks and instead pass the event on to one function.

(This is so the User can select a widget to perform meta operations. Part explanation here:         [Get variable name of Qt Widget (for use in Stylesheet)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983345/get-variable-name-of-qt-widget-for-use-in-stylesheet/8983694#8983694) )

The User would pick a widget (to do stuff with) by clicking it, and of course clicking a button must not cause the button's bound function to run.

What is the correct (most abstracted, sensible) method of doing this?
(which doesn't involve too much new code. ie; not subclassing every widget)
Is there anything in Qt designed for this?

So far, I am able to retrieve a list of all the widgets in the program (by calling

```
QObject.findChildren(QtGui.QWidget)
```

so the solution can incorporate this.

My current horrible ideas are;

- Some how dealing with all the applications events all the time in one
  function and not letting through the events when I need the
  application to be dormant.
- When I need dormancy, make a new transparent widget which recieves
  mouse clicks and stretch it over the entire window. Take coordinates
  of click and figure out the widget underneath.
- Somehow create a new 'shell' instance of the window.

THANKS!
(Sorry for the terrible write-up; in a slight rush)

---

python 2.7.2
PyQt4
Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can intercept events send to specific widgets with [QObject::installEventFilter](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

Comment: This is exactly the solution. If you want to 'steal' all events, put an event filter on the qApp and it'll keep any children from receiving them.

Comment: event filtering did nothing. Even though all events are ignored, clicking the buttons still runs the functions!  (Unless I'm stupid and don't know what I'm doing; true)

Comment: If you want to stop events being processed further, make sure you return true from your eventFilter().  Also, filtering all events is a very bad idea - only filter user input.  An even more straightforward way of achieving this would be to call setEnabled(false) on your top level widget.

Answer (score 1):

graphite answered this one first so give credit where credit is due.

For an actual example in PySide, here's an example you might draw some useful code from:

my_app.py

```
from KeyPressEater import KeyPressEater

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    eater = KeyPressEater()
    app.installEventFilter(eater)
```

KeyPressEater.py

```
class KeyPressEater(QObject):

    # subclassing for eventFilter


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

        if self.ignore_input:
            # swallow events
            pass
        else:
            # bubble events 

        return QObject.eventFilter(self,obj,event)
```

Comment: Don't really understand the class structure. (How do you have an attribute of ignore_input? You didn't have a constructor for KeyPressEater). I'll certainly look into the eventFilter though. Thanks!