# How do I style a Qt Widget not its children with stylesheets?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a:

```
class Box : public QWidget
```

and it has

```
this->setLayout(new QGridLayout(this));
```

I tried doing:

```
this->setStyleSheet( "border-radius: 5px; "
                     "border: 1px solid black;"
                     "border: 2px groove gray;"
                     "background-color:blue;");

this->setStyleSheet( "QGridLayout{"
                         "background-color:blue;"
                         "border-radius: 5px; "
                         "border: 1px solid black;"
                         "border: 2px groove gray;"
                     "}"
                   );

this->setObjectName(QString("Box"));
this->setStyleSheet( "QWidget#Box {"
                         "background-color:blue;"
                         "border-radius: 5px; "
                         "border: 1px solid black;"
                         "border: 2px groove gray;"
                     "}"
                   );
```

but the first affects only the items that are added, the other two do nothing. I want the box itself to have rounded corners and a border (bonus for how to do lines between rows).

How do I get the stylesheet to affect the Box widget, not its children?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To be more precise I could have used:

```
QWidget#idName {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

or

```
Box {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

The latter is easier, in my opinion, as it doesn't require the use of id names.

The main problem with why these weren't working though is because this is considered a custom widget and therefore needs a custom paint event:

```
 void Box::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

This was taken from: [Qt Stylesheet for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget)

Comment: It's not because the widget is a custom widget, but because it inherits from the base `QWidget` class whose `paintEvent` function doesn't do anything. If you inherited from `QFrame` instead, you would already have a working `paintEvent` function.

Answer (score 8):

You need to identify the object class and instance, like in regular CSS.

```
QWidget#BoxName
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border: 2px groove gray;
}
```

This is the same answer as here: [Get variable name of Qt Widget (for use in Stylesheet)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983345/get-variable-name-of-qt-widget-for-use-in-stylesheet)

```
box->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("QWidget#box\n"
"{\n"
"    border-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border: 2px groove gray;\n"
"}\n"
""));
```

Comment: That's the name you've given to your instance of Box; within the constructor you could use `objectName()` e.g.: this->setStyleSheet(sprintf("QWidget#%s ..." % this->objectName()))

Comment: I understood how to get the name, it just isnt working. see question.

Comment: Looks like you missed a quote: `"QWidget#Box {"`. This is the right approach, as for the specific syntax you will have to figure this out as i use QT with Python, not C.

Comment: Try it in the QT Designer, it works for me. You should be able to copy the code from there; i have added mine to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can write your custom `setStylesheet` function, Make the object address as object name by default. for example in python:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def setStylesheetOnlySelf(self, stylesheet: str) -> None:
        objectName = self.objectName() if self.objectName() != "" else str(id(self))
        self.setObjectName(objectName)
        self.setStyleSheet("#%s {%s}" % (objectName, stylesheet))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

widget = MyWidget()
widget.setStylesheetOnlySelf("background: white")
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```